# iframe with src as dynamic property

Tags: angularjs, iframe

Good afternoon. I have an Angular JS app which is correctly raising an SSRS report. But it is hardcoded. I want to raise the url from the configuration.

To do this, I replaced this in the view:

```
<div>
       <iframe ng-src="{{vm.report}}" height="600" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

where: vm.report is:

```
function BalancesController(.......) {
    var vm = this;
    
     function initialize() {
          vm.report = window.ReportLoadBaskets + "?rs:Embed=true";
     }
}
```

But I get this error:

Error: $sce:insecurl
Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked
Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://pcxxx/Reports/report/Gener/Events?rs:Embed=true

How can I solve that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

please let me know if this works for you..

```
<div>
    <iframe ng-src="{{vm.report}}" height="600" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>


function BalancesController($sce) {
    var vm = this;

    function initialize() {
        var src = window.ReportLoadBaskets + "?rs:Embed=true";
        vm.report = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);                    

    }
}
```